# Character format cannot change to Date format

Tags: r, date, as.date

I have a data and there is a column called `Date`, I input the data into R.
Here is my data:

```
unique(data$Date)
 [1] ""           "2016/12/20" "2016/12/27" "2017/1/7"   "2017/1/27"  "2017/2/1"   "2017/2/2"   "2017/2/5"   "2017/2/6"   "2017/2/7"  
[11] "2017/2/8"   "2017/2/10"  "2017/2/11"  "2017/2/13"  "2017/2/14"  "2017/2/15"  "2017/2/17"  "2017/2/16"  "2017/2/24"  "2017/2/19" 
[21] "2017/2/21"  "2017/2/20"  "2017/2/26"  "2017/2/22"  "2017/3/2"   "2017/2/25"  "2017/2/28"  "2017/3/1"   "2017/3/4"   "2017/3/5"  
[31] "2017/3/6"   "2017/3/10"  "2017/3/8"   "2017/3/9"   "2017/3/11"  "2017/3/12"  "2017/3/13"  "2017/3/15"  "2017/3/29"  "2017/5/13" 
[41] "2015/10/5"  "2016/2/22"  "2015/3/6"   "2015/3/7"   "2015/10/15" "2015/3/9"   "2016/1/30"  "2015/10/29" "2015/10/24" "2015/10/17"
[51] "2016/1/8"   "2015/9/24"  "2016/2/15"  "2015/12/8"  "2015/12/10" "2016/2/6"   "2015/11/29" "2016/1/23"  "2015/10/11" "2016/2/16" 
[61] "2015/9/28"  "2016/1/29"  "2015/11/27" "2015/10/12" "2015/11/1"  "2015/11/16" "2015/10/10" "2015/11/30" "2016/1/2"   "2016/1/21" 
[71] "2016/4/22"  "2015/10/21" "2015/11/12" "2015/12/28" "2015/12/30" "2015/11/6"  "2015/10/8"  "2015/12/6"  "2016/1/24"  "2016/1/17" 
[81] "2016/2/26"  "2016/3/6"   "2016/2/17"  "2016/1/11"  "2015/12/3"  "2016/2/11"  "2015/11/22" "2015/10/2"  "2015/10/3"  "2015/11/4" 
[91] "2016/2/10"  "2015/12/9"  "2015/10/9"  "2015/12/1"  "2016/2/25"  "2016/1/19"  "2016/1/18"  "2015/12/13" "2016/2/14"  "2016/3/10" 

class(data$Date)
[1] "character"
```

I change this `character` to `date` format with `as.Date()`:

```
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date)
Error in charToDate(x) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I don't know how to figure out. I think the problem is `""` in the data. I also has another column called `Date2` but this column doesn't contain `""` in it.
Any suggestion?

Also, If I want to do `as.Date` with two columns at the same time and define specified format like `as.Date(x, "%Y/%m/%d"), how can I do?

```
data[,c("Date", "Date2") := lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols = c("Date", "Date2")]
```

Comment: Specify the format of the date. `as.Date(x, "%Y/%m/%d")`

Comment: @RonakShah - I think it should automatically recognise that format

Comment: @SymbolixAU Ideally, it should because `as.Date("2017/01/01")` returns proper date. Maybe the digit precision matter ?

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks. it works. However, I don't know why it needs to add `"%Y/%m/%d"`.

Comment: It has to do with the first case being `""` - compare `as.Date(c("","2015/10/5"))` vs `as.Date(c("2015/10/5"))`. R can not read minds (yet) unfortunately.

Comment: yep. I got it. It works even for `as.Date("2017/1/1")` without any `format` but it is because you have one empty value in the beginning which makes it important to mention the format.

Comment: Maybe I can change `""` to `NA` at first and then change to `date` format? Is that possible?

Comment: So does `as.Date` check the first item to 'guess' the format, and then apply that to each subsequent one? Because `as.Date(c("2015/10/5", ""))` is fine. But if the first one is `""`, then it has issues?

Comment: @SymbolixAU - you can see this checking if you type `as.Date.character` in the console and inspect the code. It seems to do what you are guessing it does.

Comment: For the updated question, `data[, `:=`(Date = as.Date(Date), Date2 = as.Date(Date2))]` should do (with back-ticks around the `:=`)

Comment: @SymbolixAU yes, it works. However, my code cannot work. I don't know why.

Comment: Have you specified the `"%Y/%m/%d"` format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As established in the comments, the answer is that you need to specify the format of the date you're converting. Which in your case is `"%Y/%m/%d"`

```
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, "%Y/%m/%d")
```

---

### Explanation

The **reason** you need to do this is because the first entry in your vector is `""`, AND you haven't specified the format.

The `as.Date` function, when applied on a character, first checks to see if the `format` argument is missing. If it is, it tries to guess the format based on the first element of the vector.

It tests for both `"%Y-%m-%d"` AND `"%Y/%m/%d"` formats by doing

```
xx <- ""
strptime(xx, "%Y-%m-%d")
NA
strptime(xx, "%Y/%m/%d")
NA
```

More specifically, it uses the following test (where `xx` is the first element of your vector)

```
if(is.na(xx) || 
    !is.na(strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "GMT")) || 
    !is.na(strptime(xx, f <- "%Y/%m/%d", tz = "GMT"))){
  print("success!")     ## I added this print statement for illustration purposes
}else{
  stop("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format")
}
```

So as you can see, `xx` evaluates to `FALSE` in all the `if` conditions, so the function has to enter the `stop` method.

To demonstrate, see the results of these statements

```
as.Date(c("2015/10/5", ""))  
# [1] "2015-10-05" NA
## SUCCESS, because it can 'guess' the first entry's format

as.Date(c("", "2015/10/5"))  
## ERROR: can't 'guess' the first entry's format

as.Date(c("2015/10/5", ""), format = "%Y/%m/%d") 
# [1] "2015-10-05" NA
## SUCCESS, because you've specified the format

as.Date(c("2015-10/5", "")) 
## ERROR: you haven't specified the format, 
## AND it's not one of the 'guessed' options ("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ymd()` function in the `lubridate` package to convert the dates, and the empty strings will be converted to NA. For example,

```
> library(lubridate)
> (newdates <- ymd(dates))
   [1] NA           "2016-12-20" "2016-12-27" "2017-01-07" "2017-01-27" "2017-02-01" "2017-02-02" "2017-02-05"
   [9] "2017-02-06" "2017-02-07" "2017-02-08" "2017-02-10" "2017-02-11" "2017-02-13" "2017-02-14" "2017-02-15"
   [17] "2017-02-17" "2017-02-16" "2017-02-24" "2017-02-19" "2017-02-21" "2017-02-20" "2017-02-26" "2017-02-22"
   [25] "2017-03-02" "2017-02-25" "2017-02-28" "2017-03-01" "2017-03-04" "2017-03-05" "2017-03-06" "2017-03-10"
   [33] "2017-03-08" "2017-03-09" "2017-03-11" "2017-03-12" "2017-03-13" "2017-03-15" "2017-03-29" "2017-05-13"
   [41] "2015-10-05" "2016-02-22" "2015-03-06" "2015-03-07" "2015-10-15" "2015-03-09" "2016-01-30" "2015-10-29"
   [49] "2015-10-24" "2015-10-17" "2016-01-08" "2015-09-24" "2016-02-15" "2015-12-08" "2015-12-10" "2016-02-06"
   [57] "2015-11-29" "2016-01-23" "2015-10-11" "2016-02-16" "2015-09-28" "2016-01-29" "2015-11-27" "2015-10-12"
   [65] "2015-11-01" "2015-11-16" "2015-10-10" "2015-11-30" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-21" "2016-04-22" "2015-10-21"
   [73] "2015-11-12" "2015-12-28" "2015-12-30" "2015-11-06" "2015-10-08" "2015-12-06" "2016-01-24" "2016-01-17"
   [81] "2016-02-26" "2016-03-06" "2016-02-17" "2016-01-11" "2015-12-03" "2016-02-11" "2015-11-22" "2015-10-02"
   [89] "2015-10-03" "2015-11-04" "2016-02-10" "2015-12-09" "2015-10-09" "2015-12-01" "2016-02-25" "2016-01-19"
   [97] "2016-01-18" "2015-12-13" "2016-02-14" "2016-03-10"
> is.Date(newdates)
 [1] TRUE
```